# What's the right statistical analysis for temperature effects on turtle hibernation over time?

Tags: self-study, ecology, biostatistics

I have an assignment in which I am supposed to create a theoretical study design within a biological field. Currently, I have data from a group of seven turtles. For the assignment, I thought it would be interesting to study the effect that temperature has on the hibernation cycle of box turtles; however, I’m not sure what statistical analysis is best
My null hypothesis is that temperature does not have a significant effect on the duration of the hibernation cycle of box turtles in my area from 2015-2020.
However, I do not have enough experience with statistics to know how best to analyze the data.
For the data themselves, each of the seven turtles was tracked roughly once a week for each of the years that I am examining. The start of hibernation is considered two consecutive weeks (two data points) in which the turtle did not move. The end of hibernation is marked as the week in which the turtle begins moving again in the spring. I also have the air and ground temperatures for each day that the turtles were successfully tracked. So, below is a simplified chart of what my data looks like for each turtle. There is some variation in the start and end dates of hibernation for individual turtles between years.

Turtle A

| Date | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Day 1 | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp |
| Day 2 | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp | Ground Temp, Air Temp |
| Etc.. |  |  |  |  |  |  |

My question is, what is the best way that should analyze this data, given my hypothesis? I considered a regression of average temperature against hibernation duration, as well as an ANOVA (binning temperatures) because I have so few data points. However, because the same turtles are tracked for multiple years, I am concerned that the lack of independence between turtles will cause problems for these basic statistics.

Comment: Hi! A few keywords to get you started. A generalized mixed model would be appropriate in this case. You need to choose a distribution for your outcome variable (hibernation duration). I am not an expert on that but perhaps you can use the gamma distribution if durations are short. I am sure someone has used a more appropriate distribution in the literature, so be sure to read relevant research papers. There you will also find which ways are considered appropriate to adjust for the point in the season.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I’m voting to close this question because it is fundamentally about statistics (for which there is a separate site) rather than about biology as defined in the [help]. It is also ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework), but untagged and under researched. Both of those are sufficient reasons for closure. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details and  [edit] or delete your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by re-shaping your data into a table where each row contains a "response" (the duration of hibernation), your predictors (ground temp, air temp) and any other info to include in the mode (year, turtle etc). Something like this:

```
Hibernation_duration    Turtle   Year   Air_temp   Ground_temp
                  40         A   2015         24            15
                  35         A   2016         27            16
                  41         A   2017         24            15
                  34         A   2018         27            16
                  43         A   2019         24            15
                  33         A   2020         27            16
                  45         B   2015         24            15
                  32         B   2016         27            16
```

etc...

It sounds like you have defined your response already. However, you may need to give  some thought to how you want to define your predictors. e.g. you could use the mean temperature for that whole year, or you could use the mean temp over the two weeks prior to hibernation. You will have to use your expert knowledge to decide what is appropriate. If you include multiple predictors (i.e. ground temp and air temp) check that they're not too correlated - variation inflation factors are useful for this.

You can then use a generalized mixed model to test your hypothesis. As vkehayas notes in the comments, you will need to decide what distribution to specify for your response variable - gamma may be appropriate as it is bounded below by zero, but has no upper bound. You don't want to be able to model negative durations, although if they're high enough, a normal (Gaussian) distribution may also work.

If you're using R, you can specify a generalized mixed model like this:

```
library(lme4)
model <- glmer(Hibernation_duration ~ Air_temp + Ground_temp + (1|Turtle) + (1|Year), family=Gamma, data=data)
```

Here, Turtle and Year are included as random effects (Note, you would have to  convert Year to a character/factor variable first). You could do some reading around these to understand them more, and how they're useful for your type of study.